# Web Service Testing Site

Tags: testng, soapui, web-service, postman

I practice web services testing but I don't have any web service testing site. Could anyone please suggest a good web service testing site?
Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try https://www.mockable.io

There is a free plan that will allow you to build your own REST and Soap services and that will be enough to practice your interaction trials.

Comment: Any other good website to practice web service testing?

Comment: @peterwkc what is wrong with the mentioned one? I mean which features are you missing?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to practise webservice testing only and no development of API's. You can try out this project: https://github.com/spring-petclinic/spring-petclinic-rest

Perfect project for trying out testing REST services wit ha new tool/framework.